# Correctly creating a Navigation Class in Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

In this ASP.NET MVC application all the database information is set 'Code-first' in the application.
There is a Model class called 'Customer' which is already migrated to the database,  and populated with five 'Customers'

Now I want to add a 'Navigation Class' called MembershipType.  Each Customer will have one of four different 'MembershipTypes'

It looks like this

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class MembershipType
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public short Fee { get; set; }
        public byte Discount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added the fields MembershipType and MembershipTypeId to the existing Customer class, like so, and tried to add-migration & update-database.

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models

{
   public class Customer
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

       //These two fields were added as a 'Navigation Class'
       public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
       public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when I update-database in the Package Manager

**The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.MembershipTypes_MembershipTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-WebApplication3-20160817102050", table "dbo.MembershipTypes", column 'Id'.**

I've looked at other programs that I've made recently and have not had this 'foreign key' problem before when the navigation class is not populated in the database.

I'm trying to understand why this error is happening with the foreign key...

Comment: is the code above all of it? or do you have some `DataAnnotations` or `FluentApi` to set up the relationship?

Comment: There are not DataAnnotations or FluentApis,  The relationship should be apparent to Entity from the MembershipType and MembershipTypeId fields referenced in the Customer Class

Answer (score 0):

For this EF convention to work, your `MembershipType` class should have a collection of Customers:

```
public class MembershipType
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
    public short Fee { get; set; }
    public byte Discount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers {get; set;}//this needs to be present 
                //otherwise EF is not able to know what type of relationship to create
}
```